# Make certain programs (like vim) open up in an adjacent terminal inside of terminator

Tags: bash, gnome, terminator

Let's say I have terminator open and split vertically as to give me two terminals side by side. What I would like to do, is to call

> vim example.sh

on the right hand side, and have vim open the file on the left hand side. Is something like that possible, perhaps some sort of an alias?

Comment: Do you want to open the same file on both sides?

Comment: @haifzhan preferably not, since I would like to expand this to a terminator window that has more than 2 terminals on it.